# How to import git commit from development to testing in Aegir

Tags: 7, drush, version-control, aegir

So, I have established Aegir to take care of my sites workflow.

Now I made changes to my development site, used git to load the commit to development site. How do I import the latest commits to Staging or Production ?

[image: Aegir workflow]

Comment: you can use **git pull** command to get changes from server.

Comment: you mean to go to **test** and do `git pull` and again go to **prod** and do `git pull`? that's not how **Aegir** works, it creates installation profile

Comment: you can either update one of your existing profiles in Aegir using git pull, or you can build a new profile for Aegir

Answer (score 0):

With the [Hosting site Git](https://drupal.org/project/hosting_site_git) module you can create a git pull task from the hostmaster frontend.

> This module extends [Aegir](http://community.aegirproject.org/) with the option to do a 'git pull' in a site directory.

Answer (score 0):

From stage to production (in case every custom module, feature, theme have it's own repository)

1. Create a new tag on your repository.
2. Create a new make file that gets this tag-version of the module, theme etc.
3. Create with this make file a new platform in Aegir.
4. Migrate the site to the new platform.

We assume that on the production server we must have the absolute control over the code.
It's a painful but reliable workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The assumed architecture model is problematic.  You shouldn't have an "Aegir hub" server separately from Dev, Staging and Prod servers; you should simply have Aegir Dev, Aegir Staging and Aegir Prod servers.

To move sites from one Aegir environment to another, you would [remotely import them](https://www.drupal.org/project/hosting_remote_import).

For details on this topic, see [Aegir DevOps: Deployment Workflows for Drupal Sites](https://consensus.enterprises/blog/aegir-devops-deployment-workflows-drupal-sites/).

For updating code on whichever server, you would navigate to *Platforms » Add Platform*.  From there, you would choose a deployment strategy involving Git.  See the [Deployment Strategies](https://docs.aegirproject.org/usage/advanced/deployment/) documentation page for more information.